# For loop not adding JSON elements into array even when triggering

Tags: arrays, json, swift, for-loop, swiftui

So say I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "state": "ready",
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "11f54570-9ea5-11e9-a4b3-717499928918",
        "name": "applications",
        "public": true,
        "update_date": "2019-07-04T21:45:41.959Z"
    },
    {
        "state": "ready",
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "4128b600-976c-11e9-8289-717499928918",
        "name": "home",
        "public": true,
        "update_date": "2019-06-25T17:11:21.696Z"
    },
    {
        "state": "ready",
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "11f67df0-9ea5-11e9-a4b3-717499928918",
        "name": "resources",
        "public": true,
        "update_date": "2019-07-04T21:45:41.967Z"
    },
    {
        "state": "ready",
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "11f2d470-9ea5-11e9-a4b3-717499928918",
        "name": "teams",
        "public": true,
        "update_date": "2019-07-04T21:45:41.944Z"
    }
]
```

I am trying to create a list containing a cell for every item in this JSON. My instinct here is to create an array of my cells that I can display into my list. The way I am doing this is by using a For Loop to go through each of these and initialize a cell, based on their data.

However, if passed the JSON that i've shown here, the only cell that gets added to my array is the last one.

I am using SwiftyJson to handle my Json data.

My for loop is as follows:

```
for (key, subJson) in testJson {
            arrayFromJson.append(FileCell(name: subJson["name"].string ?? "nil", fileType: subJson["type"].string ?? "nil", fileDesc: subJson["id"].string ?? "nil"))
        }
```

my arrayFromJson is made with

```
@State var arrayFromJson: Array<FileCell> = []
```

my FileCell is defined by:

```
struct FileCell: Identifiable,View {
    var name: String
    var fileType: String
    var fileDesc: String
    var id = UUID()

    var body: some View{


        var FileImage: String

        var fileName = ("\(name).\(fileType.lowercased())")

        var isFolder = false

        let ImageType = ["JPEG","JPG","PNG","GIF","BMP"]
        let TextType = ["TXT","TEXT","DOC","XML","RTEXT"]

        if(fileType.uppercased() == "FOLDER"){
            isFolder = true
        }

        if(isFolder){
            FileImage = "folder.fill"
            fileName = name
        }else if ImageType.contains(fileType.uppercased()) {
            FileImage = "photo.fill"
        }
        else if TextType.contains(fileType.uppercased()) {
            FileImage = "doc.text.fill"
        } else {
            FileImage = "xmark.octagon.fill"
        }

        return

            HStack{

            VStack(alignment: .center) {

                Image(systemName: FileImage).font(.largeTitle).frame(width: 50)

            }

            Divider()

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5.0) {
                Text(fileName)
                    .font(.title)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                Text(fileDesc)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and is displayed in my view as a navigation link with

```
List {
                ForEach(arrayFromJson){result in

                    NavigationLink(destination: destinationDeterminer(fileName: result.name, fileType: result.fileType)){
                                result }    
                }
        }
```

The app works fine if I just make an array and put my FileCells in by hand (in fact that's what I have done in my debug preview). In this example, I should have 4 cells being created but I only receive one cell (Teams).

EDIT: Adding additional information by request

JSON is retrieved from the website with this code

```
func URLRetrieve(URLtoFetch: String) -> String {    
    var Value = "No URL"    
    if(URLtoFetch != ""){                        
            if let url = URL(string: URLtoFetch) {                
                do {
                    let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
                    //print(contents)
                    Value = contents                    
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to load content from URL")
                    Value = error.localizedDescription
                }
            }        
    }    
    return Value        
}
```

JSON is processed from String with this code

```
func processJSONFromString(jsonString: String) -> JSON {

    var json: JSON = -1

    if let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        do {
            json = try JSON(data: dataFromString)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to Convert Json")
        }
    }
    return json
}
```

testJson is generate using these two methods in tandom (one to retrieve the URL as a string, the other processes the JSON for use)

EDIT: Additional expiriment I did to provide more information

when adding the line

```
print(subJson["name"].string ?? "nil")
```

the "name" of every dictionary in the JSON was printed. However, the only item in the array is still "teams"

Comment: Can you show the json parsing code and how it connects to the for-loop? I can show you a working solution based on JSONDecoder if you want. The list looks pretty sleek btw

Comment: What does testJson contain? Your json looks like an array of dictionaries but it looks like your for loop is for a dictionary and not an array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have added the information you have requested to my post

Comment: @Fabian I have added the information you have requested to my post

Comment: Well I still don’t understand how that for loop works and what’s in testJson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following json parse logic, maybe it works better. I sadly don't know enough and haven't seen enough to know the specific problem you ran into.

```
import SwiftUI
import os

let data = """
[
{
"state": "ready",
"type": "folder",
"id": "11f54570-9ea5-11e9-a4b3-717499928918",
"name": "applications",
"public": true,
"update_date": "2019-07-04T21:45:41.959Z"
},
{
"state": "ready",
"type": "folder",
"id": "4128b600-976c-11e9-8289-717499928918",
"name": "home",
"public": true,
"update_date": "2019-06-25T17:11:21.696Z"
},
{
"state": "ready",
"type": "folder",
"id": "11f67df0-9ea5-11e9-a4b3-717499928918",
"name": "resources",
"public": true,
"update_date": "2019-07-04T21:45:41.967Z"
},
{
"state": "ready",
"type": "folder",
"id": "11f2d470-9ea5-11e9-a4b3-717499928918",
"name": "teams",
"public": true,
"update_date": "2019-07-04T21:45:41.944Z"
}
]
"""

// MARK: - Folder
struct Folder: Codable, Identifiable {
    let state, type, id, name: String
    let folderPublic: Bool
    let updateDate: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case state, type, id, name
        case folderPublic = "public"
        case updateDate = "update_date"
    }
}

typealias Folders = [Folder]

struct FileCell: Identifiable,View {
    init(file: Folder) {
        self.name = file.name
        self.fileType = file.type
        self.fileDesc = file.id
    }

    var name: String
    var fileType: String
    var fileDesc: String
    var id = UUID()

    var body: some View{


        var FileImage: String

        var fileName = ("\(name).\(fileType.lowercased())")

        var isFolder = false

        let ImageType = ["JPEG","JPG","PNG","GIF","BMP"]
        let TextType = ["TXT","TEXT","DOC","XML","RTEXT"]

        if(fileType.uppercased() == "FOLDER"){
            isFolder = true
        }

        if(isFolder){
            FileImage = "folder.fill"
            fileName = name
        }else if ImageType.contains(fileType.uppercased()) {
            FileImage = "photo.fill"
        }
        else if TextType.contains(fileType.uppercased()) {
            FileImage = "doc.text.fill"
        } else {
            FileImage = "xmark.octagon.fill"
        }

        return

            HStack{

                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image(systemName: FileImage).font(.largeTitle).frame(width: 50)
                }

                Divider()

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5.0) {
                    Text(fileName)
                        .font(.title)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Text(fileDesc)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct FilesFromJSONView: View {
    @State var folders: [Folder] = []

    func parse() {
        let folders = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Folders.self, from: data.data(using: .utf8)!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.folders = folders
        }
        os_log("Parse folders: count = %d", folders.count)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Folders")
                List {
                    ForEach(folders){ (result: Folder) in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text(result.id)){
                            FileCell(file: result) }
                    }
                }.onAppear{
                    self.parse()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer a tad more? I'm slightly confused on how this interfaces with the example?

Comment: You just take the line which decodes the folders, map each `Folder` to a `FileCell` and assign them to `arrayFromJson`. It's basically the alternative to `SwiftyJSON` and avoids it's  semi-manual parsing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to map the ```Folder``` to the ```FileCell``` here?

Comment: @Vapidant I added how I used it above, I hope it helps.

Comment: while I like your implementation more than my previous one, it still does not seem to work. I have changed my code to run like the example you have provided, however, this still doesn't seem to work. My view now displays zero cells when using this method

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/nGNvSeG) you can see how it looks like on macOS, iPad Pro, iPhone XR. Don't forget to drag mouse/finger press and drag to the right to open the folders list view. It is using exactly the code I posted.

Comment: Does `Parse folders: count =` show up in the Console output for you? If not then on appear does not execute the parse method as it should and it's obvious why folders do not appear. You could do it inside an `init(...)`-method instead of later inside on appear.

Comment: the output does not appear in the console output, and it did not appear when placed in the ```init(...)```

Comment: Then it is not parsing as it should. If you figure out why and fix it maybe the folders can be shown :-)

Comment: i'm stupid, I put the ```.onAppear{self.parse()}``` on the wrong thing causing the parse to never trigger. Thanks for your help and patience :-)